# Arguments to be passed to take-off AT command in ar.drone

Tags: at-command, ar.drone

I am writing a program to control the drone using a C++ program.
I am using the AT commands to control the drone.
I was able to receive the navigational data by sending a small packet to the port
5554.
But the program is getting stuck at the drone take-off function:

sprintfAT*REF="%u, x",sequence number.

Now my question what should the value of x be? Only the eighth bit has to be set to one for take-off. So in that case its value should be 11540100. But I found many examples in which its value is 290718208. I tried to take-off the drone using both the values but the drone din't take-off. What value should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MAPGPS on the arDrone api forum:
https://projects.ardrone.org/boards/1/topics/show/852

> Setings: AT*CONFIG=1,\"control:altitude_max\",\"2000\"
>
> **Basic controls**
>
> Takeoff:   AT*REF=101,290718208
>
> Landing:   AT*REF=102,290717696
>
> Hovering:  AT*PCMD=201,1,0,0,0,0

Of course the first parameter (101,102,etc..) should be replaced with the correct sequence number.

Comment: thanks for the reply. do u know how the command can be sent recursively using sprintf. i am trying it but the drone is nt responding..

Comment: You should add it on while loop that runs in a separate thread. The key is thread+mutex. And double check you are really connected to the drone (SSID) and you are sending packet to the right UDP port.

Answer (score 0):

From the [AR.Drone Developer Guide](http://www.msh-tools.com/ardrone/ARDrone_Developer_Guide.pdf)'s section on `AT*REF`:

> Send this command to control the basic behaviour of the drone. With
>   SDK version 1.5, only bits 8 and 9 are used in the control bit-field.
>   Bits 18, 20, 22, 24 and 28 should be set to 1. Other bits should be
>   set to 0.

This means that if bits 8 and 9 are zero, you're still sending (using Python):

```
>>> (1 << 18) | (1 << 20) | (1 << 22) | (1 << 24) | (1 << 28)
290717696
```

If you want the drone to take off, then you **also** set bit 9 (not bit 8 as you said in your question) to 1 and get:

```
>>> (1 << 18) | (1 << 20) | (1 << 22) | (1 << 24) | (1 << 28) | (1 << 9)
290718208
```

So that's where the number 290718208 comes from.